# Wear os build internal testing got rejected from google play store

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, google-play-internal-testing

I got rejected from google play store while trying to upload internal testing build for tester.

I have the watch release type enabled in release type
[release type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S05bC.png)

They mention in the email I got **"App doesn’t mention Wear OS in store listing and also All wear SS are transparent."**,
should I add something in full description or short description or just update the screenshots for the app?

As I got another issue about the screenshot **"Issue found: Wear screenshot
Your Wear OS screenshots have one or more issue(s) as listed below."**

Is the issue only in the screenshots or should I update anything else in the app store listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this sentence to the description:
`this app is for Wear OS`

And fix your screenshots, the easiest way is to convert then to JPG to insure they are not transparent.